# Gerrit trigger install for Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, hudson, hudson-plugins, jenkins-plugins, gerrit

I'm completely stuck with Gerrit Trigger install. I installed Jenkins ver. 1.482 with the Gerrit Trigger (v2.6.0) plugin. I'm not able to configure it.

I installed a test gerrit server (v2.4.2). I have an admin user. I tried to configure Gerrit Trigger to use this access to build patches (this is a test system, I didn't want to bother to add real users).

In Gerrit Trigger options I configured gerrit access. Test connection button says conection is ok. Although I get `The connection to Gerrit is not started yet. Check the Gerrit URL in the settings`. warning on the top. I also tried to push restart at the bottom.

I've read documentation on both Hudson and Jenkins page of the plugin. I'm still unable to configure the plugin.

Do you have any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Probably Click the button to **Save** after testing, this is common mistake that you forget to save it !! I met this several times

[image]

See more explanation in https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gerrit+Trigger

Otherwise it is not clear what's your problem since this is a normal case.